# Why/how does extends filter out values in TS?

Tags: typescript

I'm really confused as to why `SetDifference` works and `type foo = 1` here:

```
type SetDifference<A, B> = A extends B ? never : A;
type foo = SetDifference<1 | 2 | 3, 2 | 3 | 4>;
```

Why isn't it `never`??

[ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20SetDifference%3CA%2C%20B%3E%20%3D%20A%20extends%20B%20%3F%20never%20%3A%20A%3B%0D%0Atype%20foo%20%3D%20SetDifference%3C1%20%7C%202%20%7C%203%2C%202%20%7C%203%20%7C%204%3E%3B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).
Each type in union (`1`, `2` and `3`) tested if it extends `2 | 3 | 4`. Only `1` is not, hence the result.

> Conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter are called distributive conditional types. Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation.
>
> For example, an instantiation of `T extends U ? X : Y` with the type argument `A | B | C` for `T` is resolved as `(A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y)`.